# Sending data to another PHP file to use data in email

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send data from one PHP file to another to echo data inputted by the user. This data (email and email_code) will then be used in a url to verify the user's email address.

My code is as follows.

If all validations pass, the following code will be run:

```
$user = new User();

$user->sendEmail();

Session::flash('home', 'Uw account is voltooid en u kunt nu <a href="inloggen">inloggen</a>!');
Redirect::to('index');
```

In my User class, the following function (`sendEmail()`) runs:

```
public function sendEmail() {
        include_once "mailer/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name

        ob_start();                      // start capturing output
        include('mailer/mail.php');             // execute the file
        $content = ob_get_contents();    // get the contents from the buffer

        $email = "";
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "";
        $mail->Password = "";
        $mail->SetFrom("");
        $mail->Subject = "";
        $mail->Body = $content;
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails
        if($send){
            echo '<center><h3 style="color:#009933;">Mail sent successfully</h3></center>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<center><h3 style="color:#FF3300;">Mail error: </h3></center>'.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        ob_end_clean();
    }
```

**Note:** I've removed some private information.

The email body is a PHP file which includes a url to verify the email.

```
<a href="https://myurl.me/activate?email=<?php echo $email; ?>&email_code=<?php echo $email_code; ?>"  target="_blank">Verify</a>
```

I've tried sending the variables through a url to the `mail.php` file so that `$email` and `$email_code` would work, but in my case, this is a lot of code changing, which causes many more errors.

So, right now I'm looking for an easier way, or some tips to pass these variables from my registration form to the `mail.php` file.

Any tips or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I really don't get the point. The mail body is a PHP file? Basically, for passing data from one roundtrip to another, you could use sessions instead (you already seem to do this).

Comment: Im also confused (not hard this early).  Im not sure what the problem is that youre having? pre or post send issue? Is the problem dealing with the 'activation' or sending the email in the first place?

Comment: How, When & Where do you generate `$email_code` ?

Comment: @jossif The PHP file is just a file which contains HTML code. This is used as the body of the email. I'm trying to pass data (email and a code) to this file to then be used in the verification url.

Comment: @ThinkTank The `$email_code` is a md5 string which contains the username and a time stamp. This is generated at the registration page.

Comment: @DevDonkey Sending the email is not an issue. This all works fine. The problem is the activation url. This should contain the `$email` and `$email_code`. So, I'm trying to pass these variables to the `mail.php` file to be used in the activation url.

Comment: Still don't get the point. If the 2nd PHP file contains the body, why not simply including it? The included code could use all your vars of the current scope then.

Comment: @jossif How would I include the file as the email body?

Comment: You are already including it ...

Comment: @ThinkTank that's correct, but I wanted to hear his idea on how to solve this.

Comment: Did you check the answer ?

Comment: @ThinkTank I will when I get back to my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you never declare `$email` nor `$email_code` in your `sendEmail()` method.

I dont know where your store thoses informations, so here are 2 choices.

First its only variable that you want to pass to `sendEmail()` method

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email_code = $_POST['email_code'];
$user->sendEmail($email, $email_code);

public function sendEmail($email, $email_code) {
    include_once "mailer/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name

    ob_start();                      // start capturing output
    include('mailer/mail.php');             // execute the file
    $content = ob_get_contents();    // get the contents from the buffer
    (...)
}
```

Second solution, those variables are contained in `User` object (which is in my opinion the best one)

```
public function sendEmail() {
    include_once "mailer/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name

    ob_start();                      // start capturing output
    $email = $this->email;
    $email_code = $this->email_code;
    include('mailer/mail.php');             // execute the file
    $content = ob_get_contents();    // get the contents from the buffer
    (...)
}
```

Comment: The first solution worked liked a charm! Thanks for the help @ThinkTank!